# Running Cython get the error "Expected an identifier or literal"

Tags: python, cython

I running cython code in Juypter

```
%%cython
def g(int x):
    return x ** 2 - x
%timeit g(100)
```

and I get the error

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def g(int x):
    return x ** 2 - x
%timeit g(100)
^
------------------------------------------------------------

.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_8761e7cbf8d4d8c5fac6d16631958fb9.pyx:3:0: Expected an identifier or literal
```

but if I running separate the two pieces of code

```
%%cython
def g(int x):
    return x ** 2 - x
```

```
%timeit g(100)
```

I can get the answer

```
48.4 ns ± 0.136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

I don't know what causes this

Comment: You need a blank line for IPython to know when the `%%cython` cell magic ends.

Comment: I add a blank line under the ```%%cython```, but the same error still occurs

Comment: I think the point is that `%timeit` isn't Cython syntax so can't work inside a Cython cell.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`%%timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) is a [line magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)  and can be used both as a *cell magic mode* or as a *line magic mode* but needs two different syntax!

`%%timeit` is used as a cell magic while `%timeit` is the line magic.

`%timeit` will time the expression written on the same line while the `%%timeit` will run the whole cell.

So now we can see the problem with you example! Using the *cell magic* is not the way to go, you should put it at the very top of your cells! This is useful when there is some setup and work that you want to time but for your single case the *line magic* version should be plenty!

Moreover you are adding to the mix the `%%cython` cell magic which may be incompatible with the `%%timeit` cell magic so beware!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it help me